# Start an Application from Another Application, including parameters.

Tags: android, android-intent

I have 2 apps. App1 and App2.
App1: an Edit Text + button
App2: just a Text View.

this is the button onClick

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent sendIntent =   getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.app2");
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(sendIntent);

        }
```

App1 should start App2 setting the text view of the App2

```
EditText text;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
            String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
            text.setText(sharedText);
        }
    }
}
```

but i have nullpointerexception. plz help and thx

Comment: If you have a question about a NullPointerException, you should at least look in the LogCat to see exactly which line causes the NullPointerException.  Most times this will answer your question, but it can also help the community with your question if it's not enough information for you to figure out on your own.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So your need is to send some data from APP1 to APP2.
 In your code, NullPointer occurs because you didn't initialize `EditText text` by calling `findViewById()`. Also, you can make coding simple.  Try as following:

APP1:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent sendIntent =   getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.app2");
        sendIntent.putExtra("my_text", "This is my text to send.");
        startActivity(sendIntent);

    }
```

APP2:

```
EditText text;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);// This was missing in your code.
    Intent intent = getIntent();

if (intent.hasExtra("my_text")) {
        String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra("my_text");
        text.setText(sharedText);
}
}
```

Comment: How can i secure the data transfer between the two Application App1 & App2. I am doing the same but i am afraid to transfer the data plain between the two application. Could you please advise what is the best practices ?